# Typescript 2.0 Cannot Find Module

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

I'm using VS Code 1.3.0 as an editor and Typescript 2.0.  I have a `tsconfig.json` in my root directory with a files property of 
`"files":["newfile.ts"]` and `newfile.ts` is in my root directory.  I ran 
`npm i --save lodash`
`npm i @types/lodash --save` and installed the definition files.  In my newfile.ts I have
`import * as _ from "lodash" and I'm getting a module not found error on lodash.  If lodash and its type are installed, why the`module not found` error?

I have restarted my editor multiple times, to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Typescript 2.0

You need to tell vscode to use it. Please setup `tssdk` [more](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/getting-started.html)

## More

Also try `tsc` on the command line. If its an error on the command line then its an error in vscode and you need to double check the code ... share the tsconfig.json / project on github etc